# A question on bi-character of finite abelian group

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, prime-numbers, abelian-groups

Setting: $G$ is a finite abelian group and any bicharacter on $G$, where a bi-character on $G$ is a map $b:G \times G \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$b(x+y,z)=b(x,z)+b(y,z),b(x,z+y)=b(x,z)+b(x,y).$$
My question assumption is: given two positive integers both greater than $2$, ie $p,q \geq 2$ and $p,q$ are coprime, and suppose we know that bi-characters $b(a_1,b_1)=\frac{x}{p}$ and $b(a_2,b_2)=\frac{y}{q}$. $x$ and $p$ are coprime and $y, q$ are coprime for some $(a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2) \in G$.

Now my question is:

Does there exist $c,d \in G$ such that $b(c,d)$ can be written as the fraction like $b(c,d)=\frac{z}{pq}$ such that $z$ is coprime to $pq$?

I can prove this when $G$ is cyclic. If $G$ is a finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_N=<\mathbb{I}>$. We use addition notation for the finite abelian group. We only need to choose $b(\mathbb{I},\mathbb{I}) \in \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$, then the bi-character on all other values are fixed since
\begin{equation}
b(m\mathbb{I},n\mathbb{I})=(mn)b(\mathbb{I},\mathbb{I})
\end{equation}
Remember that our condition becomes that $$b(a_1\mathbb{I},b_1\mathbb{I})=\frac{x}{p}=(a_1b_1)b(\mathbb{I},\mathbb{I}),b(a_2\mathbb{I},b_2\mathbb{I})=\frac{y}{q}=(a_2b_2)b(\mathbb{I},\mathbb{I}) , (x,p)=(y,q)=1.$$

It is obviously that $b(\mathbb{I},\mathbb{I})$ must be form of $\frac{z}{pq}$ and $z$ and $pq$ are coprime to each other.

**Now I am going to prove for the general case by reducing the finite abelian group into a direct sum of the cyclic group and use some elementary number theory argument.**
However, I am stuck. I am wondering is there easy way to prove it or there is a counterexample here.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/374021/34538) and its answers helping?

Comment: In the "question assumption" you talk about two bi-characters, but then the equations are about the same bi-character $b$. Also, in your argument for cyclic groups, the relation of the bi-characters $b$ and $c$ is unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I typed them wrong, the c should be b. I had edited the question

Comment: I asked this since I think this statement is correct for the general finite abelian group but I can not prove it. However, I think to prove them should be easy.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited. Basically, I assume we know one single bi-character has two values. One is x/p, another is y/q. I should write it more carefully.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose integers $m_1,m_2,n_1,n_2$ so that $m_1$ and $n_1$ are coprime to $p$ and $m_2$ and $n_2$ are coprime to $q$, and such that $n_1m_2b(a_1,b_2)=0=n_2m_1b(a_2,b_1)$.

Then
$$b(n_1a_1+n_2a_2,m_1b_1+m_2b_2)=\frac{n_1m_1x}{p}+\frac{n_2m_2y}{q}=\frac{n_1m_1xq+n_2m_2yp}{pq},$$
whose numerator is coprime to $pq$.

Comment: Thank you very much, let me check them.